# Get days from current timestamp in SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have a table:

```
ID      Timestamp
1       2010-07-27 13:14:00.000
2       2010-08-13 13:14:00.000
3       2010-12-21 13:14:00.000
```

Now I need to subtract the day from Timestamp column with current `getdate()` and get the days from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, Timestamp, getdate())
FROM   YourTable
```

**DATEDIFF**

> Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart
>   boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.

**Syntax**

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) to calculate the difference between `datetime` values.

```
declare @T table
(
  ID int,
  Timestamp datetime
)

insert into @T values
(1,       '2010-07-27 13:14:00.000'),
(2,       '2010-08-13 13:14:00.000'),
(3,       '2010-12-21 13:14:00.000')


select datediff(day, Timestamp, getdate())
from @T
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use.

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```